# Cannot login to ABP.io. No users in database

Tags: abp

I'm trying out the guide here: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-Angular-Template

The DB was created successfully in the migration as per the guide however the ABPUsers table has no records. I've used the previous framework AspNetZero and it created 1 or two user records (admin being one of them). Any idea why there are no users?

Answer (score 0):

I skipped a part in the above link. I needed to set .DbMigrator as default project and then run it once.